# Hacer referencia a variable global o constante dentro del método - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Estimados tengo este problema el siguiente código me funciona perfectamente, pero el método hace referencia a la constante declarada dentro del método , anteriormente yo hacia referencia a una variable global que la uso para recorrer un array mientras ese método se ejecutaba el array se llenaba de data, al click del botón, el problema pasa que al poner la constante dentro del método ya no funciona el array que se recorría, no solo queda allí el problema si apunto a la variable global el método de agregar no funciona bien si hago referencia a la variable global tengo que usar this, con la constante ya no es necesario, el método con la constante funciona perfecto,
que puede estar pasando, en realidad el método con la constante me va bien pero ya no tengo alcance al array que recorro, como puedo hacer Gracias.

```js
// antes hacia referenncia a una variable global
public cupones: Coupon[] = [];

//



agregar(coupon: Coupon) {
    const cupones = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cuponesArr')) || [];
    
    if(cupones.some(c => c.barCode === coupon.barCode)) {
      console.log(`${coupon.barCode} ya existe en el localstorage`);
      return false;
    } else {
      cupones.push(coupon);
      // GUARDO EN EL LOCALSTORAGE
      localStorage.Item('cuponesArr', JSON.stringify(cupones))
    }
}
```

```html
// array que nesecito recorrer mientras se ejecuta el metodo agregar
 
 <div
      class="labels_add"
      *ngFor="let coupon of cupones; let i = index"
      (click)="remove(i)"
    >
      <span class="label">
        {{ coupon.productName }}
      </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás confundiendo propiedades de una clase con variables globales. Si tienes algo como

```js
class MiComponente {
  public cupones : Coupon [];
```

La forma de acceder a esa propiedad en los métodos de la clase es usando `this`:

```js
  agregar(coupon: Coupon) {
    this.cupones = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cuponesArr')) || [];
    
    if(this.cupones.some(c => c.barCode === coupon.barCode)) {
      console.log(`${coupon.barCode} ya existe en el localstorage`);
      return false;
    } else {
      this.cupones.push(coupon);
      // GUARDO EN EL LOCALSTORAGE
      localStorage.Item('cuponesArr', JSON.stringify(this.cupones))
    }
  }
```